# Multiple categories per image (code first)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn to work with the Entity Framework core but can't get the following code to work. I need a database with an Image that has multiple categories (for filtering).

```
public class ImageCategory
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    //*************
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    //*************
    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

......

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Category name")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

.....

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png,gif,jpeg,bmp,svg")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png,gif,jpeg,bmp,svg")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png,gif,jpeg,bmp,svg")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ImageUrlFullRes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AltText { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfViews { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    //*************
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<ImageCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Add-Migrations generate the following text:

```
    PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration -context ImageContext
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
'quandar_eu.Models.Images.ImageCategory' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

If you just want to join 2 tables you don't need a primary key right? I tried to google a solution but could not find it.

Links to good tutorials/e-book helps a lot to, since I want to learn much more.

**Edit**
Thanks to Ivan Stoev. This is the final piece of code to get it all working.

```
public class ImageContext : DbContext
{
    public ImageContext(DbContextOptions<ImageContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Image> Image { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ImageCategory> ImageCategory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageCategory>().HasKey(e => new { e.CategoryId, e.ImageId });
    }
}
```

Comment: EntityFramework core or EntityFramework 6? If core, please adjust the tags, the entity-framework tag is for the old EF framework+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a *composite* PK (primary key) for `ImageCategory`. Currently it's possible only using Fluent API (reference: [EF Core: Keys (primary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys)).

In your `DbContext` derived class, override the `OnModelCreating` (if you didn't already) and add the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImageCategory>().HasKey(e => new { e.CategoryId, e.ImageId });
    // ...
}
```